# I want to speed up calculations in my C# project using System.Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm new to threading, and the examples I see online construct threads by passing a void function. However, I want to speed up computation time by returning integer values in multiple threads. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
    public int CalculateLineWins5(List<List<Symbol>> _screen)
    {
        int wins = 0;
        foreach (List<int> line in lines)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reelsNumber; i++)
            {
                lineSymbols[i] = _screen[i][line[i]];
            }
            //evaluate the win per line
            wins += CalculateWinsInLine5(lineSymbols);
        }
        return wins;
    }

    public int CalculateWinsInLine5(List<Symbol> _symbolsOnLine)
    {
        // this function assumes there could be wilds on reel 1 (and there are only 5 reels)
        int wildMultiplier = 1;
        int win = 0;
        Symbol symbol = _symbolsOnLine[0];
        if (symbol.IsPayTableSymbol)
        {
            int oak = 0;
            int oakWild = 0;

            if (symbol.IsWild)
            {
                symbol = _symbolsOnLine[1];
                if (symbol.IsWild)
                {
                    oakWild++;
                    symbol = _symbolsOnLine[2];
                    if (symbol.IsWild)
                    {
                        oakWild++;
                        symbol = _symbolsOnLine[3];
                        if (symbol.IsWild)
                        {
                            oakWild++;
                            symbol = _symbolsOnLine[4];
                            if (symbol.IsWild)
                            {
                                oakWild++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (symbol.IsPayTableSymbol)
            {
                if (_symbolsOnLine[1].Index == symbol.Index || _symbolsOnLine[1].IsWild)
                {
                    oak++;
                    if (_symbolsOnLine[1].IsWild) wildMultiplier *= _symbolsOnLine[1].Multiplier;
                    if (_symbolsOnLine[2].Index == symbol.Index || _symbolsOnLine[2].IsWild)
                    {
                        oak++;
                        if (_symbolsOnLine[2].IsWild) wildMultiplier *= _symbolsOnLine[2].Multiplier;
                        if (_symbolsOnLine[3].Index == symbol.Index || _symbolsOnLine[3].IsWild)
                        {
                            oak++;
                            if (_symbolsOnLine[3].IsWild) wildMultiplier *= _symbolsOnLine[3].Multiplier;
                            if (_symbolsOnLine[4].Index == symbol.Index || _symbolsOnLine[4].IsWild)
                            {
                                oak++;
                                if (_symbolsOnLine[4].IsWild) wildMultiplier *= _symbolsOnLine[4].Multiplier;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                win += Mathf.Max(payTable[symbol.Index][oak], payTable[0][oakWild]) * wildMultiplier;
            }
            else
            {
                win += payTable[0][oakWild] * wildMultiplier;
            }
            
        }
        return win;
    }
```

Essentially, I want to run the computations within the foreach loop above in parallel. Typically that's going to be 40 to 50 iterations of the CalculateWinsInLine5 method, so I think I'd have to create 40 to 50 threads that are computed in parallel and each return an integer value. I just don't know how. Any help or feedback on how to approach this is welcome.

Edit: My project runs random simulations of slot machine payouts. In each simulation the program goes through a large number of iterations where it generates a random set of reel stops which generate a matrix of symbols (the screen). In each iteration, the screen pay is evaluated using the CalculateLineWins5 method.
This is actually a Unity project, and interestingly enough, I already tried using the Burst compiler which makes the simulations 1.5x slower, just like Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: Bear in mind that even on a 4 core (Intel) processor, there are only 2 full FP cores.  CPU bound operations aren't a great fit for massively parallel processing.

Comment: To the person who deleted the 1st answer: The lists are typically of length 5 and the list<list<int>> are typically 10x5 matrices up to 50x5 matrices. The integer values typically range from 0 up to 2000. The computations in CalculateWinsInLine5 involve a lot of if stamements comparing int values, and simple addition and multiplication... there are about 12 different computations in that method, but the method is called about 40 to 50 times inside the CalculateLineWins5 method, and the latter method is called about 200000 times in a _short_ random simulation (which is what my project does).

Comment: Have you considered using the [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for) or [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) methods, instead of managing threads manually? Or, in case you are familiar with LINQ, to use [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I just tested Parallel.ForEach and the simulations are actually 1.5x slower.

Comment: Getting this working in multiple threads is not really the issue, getting it working faster than you current implementation poses a range of problems though, mainly we would need test data and good representation of the calculation you are doing. otherwise this will likely be hit and miss

Comment: I've provided more details in my edit and on the 2nd comment in this thread. What do you mean by test data @MichaelRandall?

Comment: I mean we can write a method and parallel it, but unless its solving your current problem the results may not much yours. Anyway the addition of your method helps a lot

Comment: This probably indicates that your workload is not parallelizable in its current state. It is either too granular, or it has too many interdependencies (or both). So either the overhead of the initial partitioning and final aggregation, or the contention for exclusive access to shared state (or both), are neutralizing the benefits of parallelism. You'll probably get similar results if you do the parallelization the hard way, by managing the threads manually.

Comment: If you really want to speed this up, then I suggest you look at doing this in on a GPU using C++/AMP ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/amp/cpp-amp-cpp-accelerated-massive-parallelism?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019 )